# How to add Elasticsearch as a service in Ambari

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin, ambari

I was wondering to know how can I add Elasticsearch as a service to Ambari portal and monitor it through that portal? ... I know it's doable via Ambari Stacks, but I don't know how doing it. I found an RPM plugin, but since the host operating system is Ubuntu 14.0.3 it wouldn't work with that.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/Symantec/ambari-elasticsearch-service
but you still have to write python

Answer (score 0):

There is no official Elasticsearch service offered in the default HDP stack. You need to create a custom service and add it to your HDP stack. You can find out more about creating custom services on the [Ambari Wiki.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Defining+a+Custom+Stack+and+Services)

Also, you can use unofficial Elasticsearch service offered by Github people. Check out [Symantec/ambari-elasticsearch-service](https://github.com/Symantec/ambari-elasticsearch-service) as suggested or [teamsoo/ambari-elasticsearch-service](https://github.com/teamsoo/ambari-elasticsearch-service)

Comment: See also [Jaraxal/ambari-elasticsearch-service](https://github.com/Jaraxal/ambari-elasticsearch-service)